# kafka connect file pulse to read JSON file into kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to load json file to kafka, and hoping to use the `file-pulse connector`.

my json file is like below:

```
{
    "field1": "string1",
    "field2": "string2",
    "field3": 9.8,
    "lastField": "2020-09-03T18:00:00"
}
```

**question** what should be the reader class for the connector's properties file? I've below

```
# File types
fs.scan.filters=io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.scanner.local.filter.RegexFileListFilter
file.filter.regex.pattern=.*\\.json$
#task.reader.class=io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.reader.WHATSHOULDitBE
```

I have tried to find the answer from the file-pulse conenctor doc or check the source code of the kafka connect filepulse connector, but I failed.

[image: checked source code]

Comment: I decided to use shell script and kafka console producer to ingest the json for now.

Comment: Does it have to be file-pulse connecter? Still anything open here or was the problem just to load a json string into a kafkatopic?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options to read JSON files using Connect FilePulse:

- `io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.reader.RowFileInputReader` :  if your file contains one JSON object per line.
- `io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.reader.BytesArrayInputReader`: if your file contains a single JSON object or array.

Then, you have to configure the built-in [`JSONFilter`](https://streamthoughts.github.io/kafka-connect-file-pulse/docs/developer-guide/filters/#jsonfilter) to actually parse the bytes[] or string line.

Configuration example:

```
"config" : {
    [...]
    "fs.scan.filters":"io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.scanner.local.filter.RegexFileListFilter",
    "file.filter.regex.pattern":".*\\.json$",
    "task.reader.class": "io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.reader.BytesArrayInputReader",
    "filters": "ParseJSON",
    "filters.ParseJSON.type":"io.streamthoughts.kafka.connect.filepulse.filter.JSONFilter",
    "filters.ParseJSON.source":"message",
    "filters.ParseJSON.merge":"true",
}
```

Here is a blog post showing how to process JSON files: [Streaming data into Kafka S01-E03 - Loading JSON File](https://dev.to/fhussonnois/streaming-data-into-kafka-s01-e03-loading-json-file-3d76)